# cocoa - add view to existing window and resize

Tags: cocoa, view, resize, window, tableview

Working on a project where I have an existing window with a view that accepts drops.  But after the drop is complete I want to add a table view and cause the window to resize larger to fit the table view.  The old appzapper app would be an example of this.

I haven't done this before and if someone could point me in the right direction of how I would do this or a tutorial that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Many ways to do it, but they all boil down to this:

1. Make a view, in your case probably a custom view with a scroll view
   and table view inside. You may not want the to wrap it in a custom
   view, but that can come in handy if you later on need to add buttons
   or other elements.
2. Set the frame of the view. You can hard code it, or you can take the
   positions of other elements and calculate it from there.
3. Tell the view to which you want to add the new view to add it
   (`addSubview:`)

Should you later want to remove it again, then call `removeFromSuperview` on the subview you just added.

Re: 1 - you can make the view in a nib or in code as you prefer.

Depending on your coding style, a trick worth using is to add the subview right in the original design in the nib, then remove it in `awakeFromNib` and keep a reference to it in your controller. You then re-size the original view.

Make sure your layout struts are set right, and you may want to wrap the other parts of the UI in their own views so they don't move around unexpectedly when you resize.

With this approach, when you add the subview again, just resize the larger view back to its original size (maybe read and stored in the controller during `awakeFromNib`), then add the subview. It will already have the right frame, and slide right back into the place it had in the nib you created in Interface Builder (or its Xcode equivalent).

Comment: Thank you for your time.  Let me test this out and I'll let you know how I do... :-)

Comment: Ok yeah I think I've got it.  I'm experimenting with fading/animating but the general idea helped me very much thanks.  I guess one thing I could ask, I see some people calling setContentView: on the window instead of adding a subview the way you described.  Are both ways fine or are there any pros/cons?  Thanks again!

Comment: For the approach described in my answer, there will have to be several different elements in the UI, preferably grouped in views - so the only way it can work is if these views are all subviews of the window's contentView. Setting the whole contentView would make sense if you swap in new content for the whole window, like a preference pane does, for instance.